# How to align the Label and Data in legend with Chartjs Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to align the data and label of legend of doughnut Chartjs like this:

[image]
[image]

I can not know how I can change the options in code :

```
doughnutChartOptions: ChartOptions = { legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      fullWidth:false,
      reverse: false,
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        boxWidth: 10,
        padding: 8,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontColor: '#003457',
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        filter: (legendItem: any, chartData: any) => chartData.datasets[0].data[legendItem.index] !== 0
      },
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem: any, data: any) {
          let indice = tooltipItem.index;
          return  data.labels[indice] ;
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

the idea is to have this  :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Add `align:'middle'` in your legend it will work's

Comment: No, I want align the contenant of legend, label and data like second picture

Comment: label and data values

Comment: at legend i Have : label and data : ```Taxes:              $80    PMI: $89``` I want unifie the space between all label and values like in the second picture

Comment: Did you try using `maintainAspectRatio: false`then add your custom CSS ?

Comment: No, How have you example please ?

Comment: First Add this `options: {
responsive: true, 
maintainAspectRatio: false
}`

Comment: Then Add your custom CSS to style as you want :)

Comment: thank you very much for your help :)